# New to windows mobile development

Tags: xcode, eclipse, visual-studio

For windows mobile development , which is the best IDE to be used?What are the pre-requisites for windows mobile development?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows App development, **Visual Studio** is definitely the software to consider. It packs many useful features and there is a lot of support available that comes with it. It is also free.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to develop for iOS, check out **Xamarin** for Visual Studio.